# Create a function that returns an array with unique items built from two arrays or an array and multiple single items

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a function that accepts an array as the first parameter, and then either another array or multiple single items as the second parameter. The function will return a new array of unique items.

What I tried first only worked for an array and multiple single values:

```
function getDedupedArray(array, ...newValues) {
    const possibleItems = [...array, ...newValues];
    const uniqueItems = [...new Set(possibleItems)]
    return uniqueItems;
}

//correctly returns [1,2,4]
const withArrayAndSingles = getDedupedArray([1,2], 1, 4);

//incorrectly returns [1,2, [1,4]]
const withTwoArrays =  getDedupedArray([1,2], [1,4]);
```

Then I tried removing the rest operator, but that only worked with two arrays:

```
function getDedupedArray(array, newValues) {
    const possibleItems = [...array, ...newValues];
    const uniqueItems = [...new Set(possibleItems)]
    return uniqueItems;
}

//throws an error
const withArrayAndSingles = getDedupedArray([1,2], 1, 4);

//correctly returns [1,2,4]
const withTwoArrays =  getDedupedArray([1,2], [1,4]);
```

How should I change my function to work for both scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten a single level of the array if it exists (this will leave the already-flat args flattened):

```js
const getDedupedArray = (arr, ...args) => [...new Set([...arr, ...args.flat()])];

console.log(getDedupedArray([1,2], 1, 4));
console.log(getDedupedArray([1,2], [1,4]));
```

Better yet, use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and spread which has better compatibility and is cleaner:

```js
const getDedupedArray = (arr, ...args) => [...new Set(arr.concat(...args))];

console.log(getDedupedArray([1,2], 1, 4));
console.log(getDedupedArray([1,2], [1,4]));
```